# How to amend more changes to a previous commit?

Tags: git

How can more changes be added to the latest commit in a repo without making another commit? I need to update the last commit with the newest set of changes that were made after that commit was made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git commit --amend`

This will add your currently staged changes to the previous commit.

If you have pushed your previous commit to a shared repository, such as GitHub, you may want to think twice about doing this however.

If anyone else has pulled down your changes, amending the commit may create merge difficulties for them. In this case it is just better to create a new commit to fix the problem.

If you haven't yet pushed the bad commit, or if you are working in a private repository and not pushing/pulling changes to/from anyone else, you don't need to worry about this.