# Remove git commit, leave files unchanged (don't remove changes)

Tags: git, commit, reset

I've done a "bad commit" yesterday (the IDE converted tabs to spaces and LF to CRLF) and I want to revert that bad commit, but I don't want the files that has been affected by the commit to get reverted back to the previous commit.

I want the affected files to remain unchanged while removing the bad commit, so I can commit the "new changes" in a new commit.

What's the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, and your working copy is still on that "faulty" HEAD, you could ["--amend" the previous commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185731/how-to-amend-more-changes-to-a-previous-commit) with the fixed files.

Comment: Yes, it's still on faulty head. I thought --amend was only for changing the commit message.

Comment: No, you can change *everything* (maybe not parents, but certainly the contents of the files).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't commit anything after, just do a `git reset --soft HEAD^`.
In the other case, but if you haven't published your history yet (didn't do a `git push` so that others already could have pulled it) just make your changes, commit them and use `git rebase -i` (interactive) to edit the history.

Comment: or leave out --soft if you also want to unstage them.

Comment: I did a git push on a different branch (but I deleted it on remote since it only had that commit).

Comment: @Mayhem93: than you can just do what Ikke, Thilo or me suggested.